# jQuery - Insert text and add string from variable

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
j(".refreshMe").html(html);

var something = $("li", html).length;

if ( something > 0 ) {
    j('.showlatest').slideDown();
}
```

and HTML:

```
<p class="showlatest"></p>
```

What I want to happen is,

```
if ( something > 0 ) {
    j('.showlatest').slideDown();
    ADD THE CONTENTS OF 'something' WITH THE TEXT 'NEW MESSAGES'
}
```

E.g.

```
<p class="showlatest">2 new messages</p>
```

I suppose I could define the 'New Messages' text as:

```
var newmessages = "New Messages";
```

But how can I then, in PHP speak, echo the results?

Comment: What's wrong with using `$('.showlatest').html(something + ' new message')`?   Note, you should be using id instead of class if these are single things.  The selectors will be more efficient.

Comment: I _highly_ recommend that you change `j` to `$` or `$j`.  `j` will be used in nested `for` loops.

Comment: Even when using this:    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Yes.  Someone will write `for (j = 0; j < something; j++)`.  You should change that to `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`.  Unless you're already using a different `$` library, you shouldn't do it at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set the text of an element, like this:

```
j('.showlatest').text(something + ' New Messages');
```